# Hide SearchView in Fragment

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I want to hide my Searchview when I scroll in my Fragment. I use a RecyclerView to retrieve my item and scroll them.

My fragment are actually like that:

[image]

When I scroll I want it to hide and then when I return to the top, I want it to show.

This is the xml of my Fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".stock.StockFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="341dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/search_layout"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            app:queryHint="Cerca Articolo">

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView>

    </LinearLayout>


    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleViewStock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to put it inside the Recycler but doesn't work, help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `NestedScrollView` for scrolling all items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".stock.StockFragment">

 <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="341dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/search_layout"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            app:queryHint="Cerca Articolo">

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView>

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleViewStock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
   </LinearLayout>

 </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

After that set `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` in java for proper scrolling.

Comment: It worked thanks, but I used (android:layout_height="685dp") in SwipeRefreshLayout and didn't use recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);